# Using CUDA and Armadillo

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cuda, armadillo

I have a `.cu` file in a 64x VS2010 project. This project is configured to extract a `.mexw64` file. Bellow there is the example I run. Inside the mex function I want to use some functions of the Armadillo linear algebra library. So When the `#include "armaMex.hpp"` is used the compiler return some errors:

1. error C3203: 'fixed' : unspecialized class template can't be used as a template argument for template parameter 'T1', expected a real type  c:....\armadillo-4.200.0\include\armadillo_bits\Mat_meat.hpp
2. error C2955: 'arma::Mat::fixed' : use of class template requires template argument list c:\ ....\armadillo-4.200.0\include\armadillo_bits\Mat_meat.hpp
3. error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation c:\ ....\armadillo-4.200.0\include\armadillo_bits\Mat_meat.hpp

I can not figure out what is causing these errors. Could you please give an explanation?

```
#include "mex.h" 
#include "armaMex.hpp"
void
    mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    mexPrintf("hello!\n");
}
```

PS: CUDA SDK 5.5 64x, VS2010

Comment: The MS VS C++ compiler is not know to be robust, nor to follow the C++ standard properly. You may want to look into using a more recent version of VS, or just a better C++ compiler in general, such as GCC. For Windows you can get it through the [MinGW project](http://www.mingw.org).

Comment: Also have a look at [NVBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublasxt), which is an implementation of BLAS that uses CUDA. You can then link with NVBLAS instead of BLAS when compiling Armadillo based programs.

Comment: I don't understand what this question has to do with CUDA programming. In your posted example, there is only a mixture of Matlab mex headers and Armadillo headers, right?

Comment: When the mex function is contained into a `.cpp` file there is not an error. However, when the same mex function is contained into a `.cu` file which is relevant 
to cuda there are some errors.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known limitation of nvcc (technically cudafe++, I think). nvcc uses file extension to determine whether a given source file should be processed for device code or passed to the CUDA preprocessors and then the device compiler. It looks like that compilation trajectory can't correctly parse some of the very complex declarations that Armadillo contains, and the compile fails. This is known to happen with Boost, Eigen and QT. I guess Armadillo is in the same boat.

The solution is to not import Armadillo headers inside a .cu file. Put your host boost code in a .cc file, device code and kernel launches in a separate .cu file and make some thin wrappers to access the kernel calls from the .cc file. You can still pass all the source to nvcc to compile into a single object file, but separating the Armadillo imports from the device code eliminates the problem of the front end choking on the complex template declarations Armadillo contains.

Comment: The code that I want to translate in cuda in this step uses armadillo. So in this step making a wrapper function that contains armadillo structures is impossible without making #include "armaMex.hpp" in the .cu file. In first step I am trying to run the current implementation with mex support to visualize the results in Matlab. The second step is gradually to go in pure C for my kernel construction. Any other suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Because Armadillo is a `.hpp` type library, is there any way to declare `#include "armaMex.hpp"` in `.cu` but send it for build in the host compiler?